# How ca i save my user details in to .txt format with only angular js1.x in my local system using with $http service

Tags: angularjs, html

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){
   
  $scope.sendData = function(){
  alert($scope.recipientName +' / '+ $scope.messageText +'</br> How can i store these values in to .txt format in my local system');
  //  $http({
       //how can i save my field data in to .txt format
   // });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Send Data</button>
 
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">User Information</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="recipientName">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="messageText"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendData();">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot access local machine files system to write or read data using web application. But downloading the `.txt` file with you content is possible using (blob)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob]

Comment: how?,  Can you add a snippet at below

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.style = "display: none";
  $scope.sendData = function() {
    var blob = new Blob([$scope.recipientName + ' / ' + $scope.messageText], {
      type: 'octet/stream'
    });
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'mytextfile.txt';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Send Data</button>

  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">User Information</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="recipientName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="messageText"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendData();">Send message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Since you cannot access file system using web application, you can download the file with your content.

Please check this snippet to download text file with your content.